# Доступ к полю или свойству по имени

Tags: c#, .net

В ActionScript 3 есть такой способ доступа к полям и свойствам экземпляра

```
obj.name = "value1"; // прямой доступ
trace(obj.name); // value1
obj["name"] = "value2"; // доступ по имени 
trace(obj.name); // value2
```

Какие есть варианты реализации такой штуки на C#?

(в догонку - возможно ли итерировать (foreach) по именам/значениям свойств?)

Comment: Взгляните на [статью о метаданных](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/dotnet/refl.xml) **Добавлено:**
Еще на msdn [сведения о метаданных](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms731823.aspx)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Проще всего через reflection:

```
FieldInfo fi = typeof(YourClass).GetField("field_name_here");
object fieldValue = fi.GetValue(yourClassInstance);
```

Итерировать можно тоже, см. пример в самом низу страницы: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.aspx

А вообще, обычно такое не нужно. Если вы расскажете, зачем вам это, может быть, мы предложим более удобный и правильный (и быстрый!) вариант.

Comment: Хм.. А если через dynamic? Там вроде можно нашаманить динамические свойства?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Да, динамические свойства можно через [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6). Но не для обычного объекта (ему некуда эти свойства «приткнуть»).

Answer (score 3):

судя по всему, вам поможет рефлексия (она же "отражения"). О ней много где написано, скажу лишь, что получение информации о типе - довольно дорогая с точки зрения производительности операция. И без серьезной необходимости прибегать к ней не стоит

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял, то можно сделать как-то так:

```
// Поле класса по имени
public object this[string key]
{
   get
   {
      var prop = GetType().GetProperties();
      var p = prop.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == key);
      if (p == null)
         return null;
      return p.GetValue(this, null);
   }
   set
   {
      var prop = GetType().GetProperties();
      var p = prop.FirstOrDefault(x => key == x.Name);
      if (p == null)
         return;
      p.SetValue(this, value, null);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно написать некоторый костыль, который будет имитировать такое поведение, перегрузив оператор `[]`

```
class LikeActionScriptClass
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public object this[string propName]
    {
        get
        {
            switch(propName)
            {
                case "Id": return Id; 
                case "Name": return Name;
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            switch(propName)
            {
                case "Id": Id = (int)value; break; 
                case "Name": Name = (string)value; break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

использование:

```
    LikeActionScriptClass obj = new LikeActionScriptClass();
    obj.Name = "name"; // прямой доступ
    obj.Name.Dump(); // name
    obj["Name"] = "name2"; // доступ по имени 
    obj["Name"].Dump(); // name2
```

Comment: при всем уважении, то, что вы предлагаете - это ужасный костыль

Comment: >Можно написать некоторый костыль...

ну так я этого и не скрывал