# Как через Assembly.Load получить переменную?

Tags: c#, dll, .net-5

Загружаю dll динамически. Есть необходимость использовать не только функции, но и переменные, как это сделать? Есть вариант написать функцию которая бы ее возвращала, но мне кажется есть более правильный способ.

Comment: Ну примерно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/110439/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8)

Comment: Переменные чего? Вы с полями или свойствами не путаете? Локальные переменные метода нельзя технически использовать за его пределами.

Comment: @Vasek, спасибо, именно это я и искал